# Invites on timelines using XFBML

Tags: facebook, fbml, timeline, xfbml, invite

In my application I am displaying custom invite dialog. This is achived by using FB.XFBML.parse method which parses FBML fb:serverFbml with other content that is responsible for displaying multi-user list.

On the side of app all looks good, invites are delivered.

But users that switched already to timeline have problem with accepting requests done this way. They cannot click on it and enter the app or even remove it. Users that are not using timeline yet can use this method to access app.

Below screen with not working example and part of edited code I am using:

[Link to image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/gv54q)

This is code copied from browser:

```
<form method="POST" target="" action="http://application_link/index.php/player/invitedfriend" content="Some content &lt;fb:req-choice label='Example label' url='http://apps.facebook.com/app_name/' /&gt; " type="closer" invite="true" id="req_form_4f840...">
```

I know that FBML is deprecated and won't be supported starting June 1 but based [documents facebook provides](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) I should be able to use fb:serverFbml without any problems thanks to FB.XFBML.parse. Any idea what might be wrong / solution to this? I would rather not want to use standard facebook dialogs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable `Requests 2.0` for your application (if not already enabled) and use the new approach to send invites. The [Requests Dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) page can help you out. The code to use the new method is quite simple too:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'My Great Request'
}, requestCallback);
```

The new approach has more advantages than the old FBML version. XFBML is the website version of FBML. Both will be removed in June so you should switch to the above method ASAP.